# Using generic type with class - type T does not satisfy the constraint

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript3.0

```
export type OptionsToType<T extends Array<{ name: Array<string>, type: keyof TypeMapping }>>
  = { [K in T[number]['name'][0]]: TypeMapping[Extract<T[number], { name: K }>['type']] }


export class CliParser<T> {

  opts: OptionsToType<T>;

  constructor() {

  }

}
```

I get this error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `T` can be any type on `CliParser`, it is too broad for `OptionsToType`. You can limit it by doing:

```
export class CliParser<T extends Array<{ name: Array<string>, type: keyof TypeMapping }>> {

  opts: OptionsToType<T>;

  constructor() {

  }

}
```

Definitely a little ugly. You may want to make `Array<{ name: Array<string>, type: keyof TypeMapping }>` its own type.